# Gift Certificate Button HTML variables

Tags: paypal

What are the html variables available for gift certificate buttons? I can not find the answer here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

I need to create this button as a non-hosted encrypted button. I want to choose my own gift certificate values so I can not host this button.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on gift certificates is pretty poor. I found this [basic guide](http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/MerchGCs/GCCreation.html) that provides some samples, but it's pretty weak. From trial and error I found that

`<input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://www.store-url.com">`

is required or the transaction will not process.
There are variables to set the minimum and maximum for the gift certificate:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="min_denom" value="5.00">
 <input type="hidden" name="max_denom" value="1000.00">
```

The doc linked above implies that you can set the color and theme with "style_color" or "style_theme" but setting the variables does not seem to do anything- at least not in the sandbox.

Unlike some other cmd types the 'no_note' variable is not required.